# Ubuntu 18.04 display bug when trying to install

Tags: kernel, 18.04, amd-processor, amdgpu

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 in my new computer, but I'm having several troubles with the display.

You can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgTRb.jpg) (this was taken at "try Ubuntu before install") that my screen divided itself in 4 pieces and I'm only able to use the first one (the left one at the top). I've taken a screenshot, but it's normal, no divide or bugged screen.

I don't know anything about kernel, but I've searched a little and have found that update kernel could be the solution.

Aditional info:

- **Motherboard:** Gigabyte GA-320-S2H;
- **CPU:** AMD Ryzen 3 2200g with GPU Vega 8 integrated;
- **Memory:** 8GB 2400MHZ DDR4;
- **Program used to create the bootable usb**: Rufus;

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the results of inadvertently hitting the Activities button or activated something similar.  It's showing you applications that you have running on your computer.  You should exit out of everything except for the installer and only work with that program.

You only have a limited amount of resources for the installer process.  The resources are the amount of ram you have in your computer.  It's using your Ram as a hard drive as well as resources for running all the applications you are trying to run.  The applications appear to be multiple instances of the file browser (plus other things taking up the other four pieces you mentioned).

If you are totally stuck, and can't do anything else, it's the results of the computer running out of resources and being locked up.

Since it's a fresh install, just cancel everything, reboot, and start the install over.  This time choose something else and pick the partition of the failed install.  The new install will overwrite what is there and you'll be able to complete your install.

To avoid this type of problem, don't start the install until you have exited out of all the applications you have been running while in the Try Ubuntu option.

Comment: I didn't install the ubuntu yet, just tested it before install and got this problem. I can't reach the option to install ubuntu, because of this bug, I can only navigate in the first part of the 4 pieces, if I put the cursor in the other ones, the cursor disappears... I've tried to install multiple times, had this bug in all of them.

Comment: What you are describing as a bug appears to be a process where it's running out of resources during your testing before you install.  Instead of clicking on the try ubuntu, click on install instead.  This way you will have more of your computer's resources available for the install process.  I mentioned the fail install because your topic **when trying to install** sounded like you were ready to install, and had actually tried.

Comment: I understand, I'll try to install.